# Odoo. Creating empty view

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

What's the easiest way to create empty view in Odoo, which renders custom HTML?

There are no such type of views in [advanced views](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html#advanced-views)

Comment: do you mean empty as without top bar and menu items?

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo, with top bar and left menu items, and control panel. But application view - empty.

Comment: so, couldn't just create a view with only HTML inside your **form** tag?

Comment: @AlessandroRuffolo, looks like possible hack. But do we have a little less messy way of doing it?

Comment: It doesn't seem an hack to me, IMHO, neither messy. In the views you can see every now and then HTML code mixed to odoo's tag, so you just put your own HTML...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with your specifications, add HTML code in `sheet` tag:

```
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="session_form_view">
        <field name="name">session.form</field>
        <field name="model">openacademy.session</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Session Form">
                <sheet>
                    Your HTML code here
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```